# IDirect3D9Ex::CreateDeviceEx fails with D3DERR_INVALIDCALL only on one OS

Tags: direct3d, directx-9

This works on an Windows 8 machine, but not on a Windows 7 Embedded machine.

Here are the values I am giving the presentation params.

[image: D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS]

The parameters to the method are as follows.

```
CreateDeviceEx(0, 
   D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, 
   displayWindow, 
   presentationParams, 
   D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED | D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE | D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, 
   NULL, 
   &device);
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why I am getting `D3DERR_INVALIDCALL`?

**UPDATE**: The problem goes away when I use D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE instead of D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONMASKABLE, but it the application. I'm not familiar with Direct3D to know why this is the case. Here is the code that renders pixels from a buffer.

```
HRESULT D3D9RenderImpl::CaptureDisplayFrame(BYTE* pBuffer, INT* width, INT* height, INT* stride)
{
    CComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9> pTargetSurface;  
    CComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9> pTempSurface;
    HR(m_pDevice->GetRenderTarget(0, &pTargetSurface)); 
    D3DSURFACE_DESC desc;       
    HR(pTargetSurface->GetDesc(&desc)); 
    if(!pBuffer)
    {
        *width = desc.Width;
        *height = desc.Height;
        *stride = desc.Width * 4; // Always ARGB32
        return S_OK;
    }
    HR(m_pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(desc.Width, desc.Height, desc.Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &pTempSurface, NULL));               
    HR(m_pDevice->GetRenderTargetData(pTargetSurface, pTempSurface));                    
    D3DLOCKED_RECT d3drect;
    HR(pTempSurface->LockRect(&d3drect, NULL, D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE | D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK | D3DLOCK_READONLY));     
    BYTE* pFrame = (BYTE*)d3drect.pBits;
    memcpy(pBuffer, pFrame, desc.Height * d3drect.Pitch);
    return pTempSurface->UnlockRect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by enabling some 3D options in Intel's graphics properties (i7).